# run multiple SqlCommand and ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

I am trying to run multiples SqlCommand in the same connection, but for some reason the program will stop at the second

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here is my code :

```
  string queryString = "SELECT DISTINCT Titre from infosHoraire where Salle='DOO';" +
                              "SELECT DISTINCT Titre from infosHoraire where Salle='FOO' and Jour <='" + finDate + "';" +
                              "SELECT DISTINCT Titre from infosHoraire where Salle='GOO' and Jour <='" + finDate + "';";


        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConsoleXMLtoDB"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            try
            {

                // on remplit le dico
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    MoviesList.Add(reader[0].ToString(), "0");
                    searchCode(reader[0].ToString(), MoviesList);
                    //Console.WriteLine(" On rajoute le code {0}", MoviesList[reader[0].ToString()]);
                }
                reader.NextResult();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (!MoviesList.ContainsKey(reader[0].ToString()))
                    {
                        MoviesList.Add(reader[0].ToString(), "0");
                        searchCode(reader[0].ToString(), MoviesList);
                    }

                }
                reader.NextResult();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (!MoviesList.ContainsKey(reader[0].ToString()))
                    {
                        MoviesList.Add(reader[0].ToString(), "0");
                    }
                }

                foreach (string key in MoviesList.Keys)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("MoviesList {0}, code {1} .", key, MoviesList[key]);

                    // RAJOUTER DONNEES HORAIRES
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO infosHoraire (Code) VALUES ('" + MoviesList[key] + "') where Titre = '" + key + "'";
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", MoviesList[key]);

                    IT STOPS HERE.
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }



            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Always call Close when done reading.
                reader.Close();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

MoviesList is a

```
  Dictionary<string, string>
```

I can't really find where the issue comes from.

It will work fine if I remove this :

```
  foreach (string key in MoviesList.Keys)
                {
                    //literaltest.Text += "<br/> dictionnaire " + key + "," + MoviesList[key];
                    Console.WriteLine("MoviesList {0}, code {1} .", key, MoviesList[key]);

                    // RAJOUTER DONNEES HORAIRES
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO infosHoraire (Code) VALUES ('" + MoviesList[key] + "') where Titre = '" + key + "'";
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", MoviesList[key]);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }
```

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: Nothing, it does not state that there is an error. But in the foreach only the first element of the Dictionary is shown in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Try to put a breakpoint on your catch and see if there is an error.

```
  catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
        }
```

Hover your mouse on e and you should be able to see the error message. Then paste it here. Its probably your query causing the problem rather than the command object

Edit. The reader object is still running which is limiting you to use the command object again. Close the reader first before trying to execute the next command

```
reader.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks, it asked me to close the datareader executing another query, wich I did. The program now finish but seems like the INSERT did not work.

Comment: Glad i could help. I would edit my answer so you can flag it as answer so we can close the question.

Comment: @TheProvost, on a side note, is it really necessary to use semi-colons to separate multiple sql statements in one executenonquery statement?

Comment: @Rod Nope. Semi-colons are not necessary

Answer (score 1):

remove `where` condition from your following `insert` query

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO infosHoraire (Code) VALUES ('" + MoviesList[key] + "') where Titre = '" + key + "'";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as below if do this it would insert the code to every row, is there another way to select them ?

Comment: An insert statement with VALUES() inserts a single row. If you don't want to insert another row, don't call it.  The WHERE clause does nothing.

Comment: I see I will try another way.

Comment: 'command.CommandText = "UPDATE infosHoraire  SET Code='" + MoviesList[key] + "' where Titre = '" + key + "'";'

Comment: Thanks for the proposition but the code value is still set at 'NULL' for every row

Comment: Ok, sorry I said nothing, it worked. It is just that uncommented by accident something that I should not. Anyway Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The SQLDataReader you used to read records is still open and using that connection. You need to close that reader before executing another command on the same connection. e.g.

```
 reader.Close();
foreach (string key in MoviesList.Keys)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("MoviesList {0}, code {1} .", key, MoviesList[key]);

                    // RAJOUTER DONNEES HORAIRES
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO infosHoraire (Code) VALUES ('" + MoviesList[key] + "') where Titre = '" + key + "'";
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", MoviesList[key]);

                    IT STOPS HERE.
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Yes, thanks to TheProvost, the message error pointed out that I had to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax for the INSERT statement is bad. You just need this

```
querystring= "INSERT INTO infosHoraire (Code) VALUES ('" + MoviesList[key] + "')";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if do this it would insert the code to every row, is there another way to select them ? I will try with SET

Answer (score 0):

The SqlCommand (command) is still busy - you can't reuse it for the insert statement. You'd need to open a new SqlConnection with a new SqlCommand. Although it'd probably be cleaner if you just moved your foreach outside of the original queries using block, since you only referencing the in memory dictionary at that point.

As mentioned, your insert statement also has a where clause which doesn't make sense...did you perhaps mean that to be an update statement?

Drop the empty catch and you'll see some exception messages, which will make your life much easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it is just like you said ^^ .

Answer (score 0):

//edit your select statement try this

```
  SELECT DISTINCT Titre from infosHoraire where Salle in ('DOO','FOO','GOO') and Jour <='" + finDate + "'";
```

Comment: Can you add some more explanation?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does works, but it doesn't really change the outcome. The INSERT/ or even UPDATE statement won't work.

Comment: he's executing multiple sql command in the same connection, if you look the 3 select statement it can combine into one select statement

Comment: @Exia0890, did you try to remove your where condition on your INSERT statement?

Comment: I did like @user2119324 said, but it did not work, although it does work when I do it manually, I will probably open another topic for this issue.